# How do I fix this problem with header files?

Tags: c, include, header-files

I am trying to call some information that I included in other files with ".h" extension to the main one. My problem is that when I try to call some function belonging to that file, I get the following error.
Here is a part of the code to give you an idea of ​​what happens to me.
I already used switch, I already used include. But when I want to use the information from "heapsort.h" I get this:

```
menu.c:(text.+0xcc): undefined reference to heapSort
menu.c:(text.+0xcc): undefined reference to mergeSort
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "heapsort.h"
#include "mergesort.h"

void options()

{
    int op = 30; 
    int n;
    int array[5];
    int i;
    int cont;
    int size;

    while (op!=0)
    {
        printf("choose one buddy:\n")
        printf("1. heap sort\n");
        printf("2. merge sort.\n");
        printf("0. exit\n");
      
        scanf("%d", &op);

        switch (op)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("heap sort\n");
                heapSort(array, n);
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("merge sort\n");
                mergeSort(array, n);
                break;

            case 0:
                printf("byebye!");
                break;

            default:   
                printf("bad option dude\n");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  You need to show a bigger fragment of code.  The free-standing `case 1` is not permissible in C.  It would have to be part of a `switch` statement inside a function.   Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.

Comment: Please read about [mre]s. When asking someone about problems in code, you must construct an example that at least *attempts* to be valid (except for the problem you can't solve). This isn't the sort of example that achieves that.

Comment: That's a linker error.  You didn't include `heapsort.o` (or `mergesort.o`) on the command line as you linked your executable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So in this case it should be "mergesort.o(array, n);" and the same with heapsort?

Comment: What it means is that you probably have 5 source files: `menu.c`, `heapsort.h`, `mergesort.h`, `heapsort.c` and `mergesort.c`.  You need to compile each of the `.c` files to an object file (`menu.c` --> `menu.o`, etc), and then you need to include all three of those on the linking command line: `cc -o program menu.o heapsort.o mergesort.o` (or equivalent).  Alternatively, you can simply list the `.c` files on the command line: `cc -o program menu.c heapsort.c mergesort.c` and the compiler will create, use and (probably, but not necessarily) remove the intermediate `.o` files.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ And, if there's yet another source file containing `main()` — other than (presumably) `menu.c` — then you need to add that too.  Your problem appears to be a basic issue of "how to build a program from multiple source files"; at least, that's my current best guess as to your problem.  The fact that the error message mentions `menu.c` rather than `menu.o` suggests you're trying `cc -o program menu.c` and that doesn't provide the code for `heapSort()` or `mergeSort()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message

```
menu.c:(text.+0xcc): undefined reference to heapSort
menu.c:(text.+0xcc): undefined reference to mergeSort
```

is not a compiler error message, but a linker one.  The meaning being that you have not included some object file (or the implementation of `heapSort` nor `mergeSort`, anywhere in the linking process)

As the comments to the question indicate, you should have provided a [Minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which, lacking the contents of the include files you use, and the compilation units for the functions `heapSort()` and `mergeSort()` it is very difficult to assess you more in the subject.

To use an external library *it's not only necessary to do proper `#include <library.h>` in the source file, but you have to add compilation results of other units in the program.*  Normally, you have add the library properly installed in your system and use the linker option `-l<libraryName>` where `<libraryName>` is the name of the library to search for implementations of the functions you call in your code, or the already compiled objects of the compilation units where those functions are implemented.  In spite you provide no information about the library you are using or the other modules of your program, no more help can be given to your question.